# DataStore over quota with both billing and datastore API enabled

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I'm getting the following error when trying to put data:

**Sorry, unexpected error: The API call datastore_v3.Put() required more quota than is available**

The problem is that I am not over quota and have both billing and Google Cloud Datastore API enabled.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Even after enabling billing you still need to set the app budget above $0 in the Developers console's App Engine settings (Project -> Compute -> App Engine -> Settings).